# Full Calendar show events as dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to modify the design of a calendar using Full Calendar. What I want to achieve is the visible events that can fit on the calendar are shown as they are, and the hidden events (events that collapsed into "+2 more") as dots. Here is how it looks so far:

```js
var dayArray = [];

$(function() {

  var todayDate = moment().startOf('day');
  var YM = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM');
  var YESTERDAY = todayDate.clone().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var TODAY = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var TOMORROW = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var NEXTMONTH = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM');

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    navLinks: true,
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
    views: {
    basic: {
      // options apply to basicWeek and basicDay views
    },
    agenda: {
      // options apply to agendaWeek and agendaDay views
    },
    week: {
      columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd D',
      titleFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'
    },
    day: {
      // options apply to basicDay and agendaDay views
    }
  },
    events: [
      {
        title: 'The AI Summit 2016',
        start: YM + '-03',
        end: YM + '-06',
        backgroundColor: "#BCE4FD",
        borderColor: "#26A8FB"
      },
      {
        title: 'Spring 2016',
        start: YM + '-09',
        end: YM + '-14',
        backgroundColor: "#BCE4FD",
        borderColor: "#26A8FB"
      },
      {
        title: 'Virtual Assistant Summit',
        start: YM + '-17',
        end: YM + '-20',
        backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
        borderColor: "#D9624F"
      },
      {
        title: "O'Reilly Summit 2016",
        start: YM + '-23',
        end: YM + '-26',
        backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
        borderColor: "#D9624F"
      },
      {
        title: 'SIGCHI 2016 Conference',
        start: YM + '-18',
        backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
        borderColor: "#D9624F"
      },
      {
        title: 'Les Inggris 2016 Q4',
        start: YM + '-11',
        backgroundColor: "#BCE4FD",
        borderColor: "#26A8FB"
      },
      {
        title: 'Minds Mastering Mac',
        start: YM + '-05',
        end: YM + '-07',
        backgroundColor: "#eee",
        borderColor: "#aaa"
      },
      {
        title: 'AAAI-16',
        start: YM + '-18',
        end: YM + '-20',
        backgroundColor: "#eee",
        borderColor: "#aaa"
      },
      {
        title: 'Service Experience',
        start: YM + '-26',
        end: YM + '-29',
        backgroundColor: "#eee",
        borderColor: "#aaa"
      },
      {
        title: 'Les Bahasa Perancis',
        start: YM + '-26',
        backgroundColor: "#B3EFDA",
        borderColor: "#00c983"
      },
      {
        title: 'SMS Las Vegas 2016',
        start: YM + '-27',
        backgroundColor: "#DACAFD",
        borderColor: "#8652FB"
      },
      {
        title: 'Leadership Training',
        start: YM + '-27',
        backgroundColor: "#DACAFD",
        borderColor: "#8652FB"
      },
      {
        title: 'Leadership Training 2',
        start: YM + '-28',
        end: YM + '-30',
        backgroundColor: "#DACAFD",
        borderColor: "#8652FB"
      },
      {
        title: 'Leadership Camp Winter 2016',
        start: YM + '-27',
        backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
        borderColor: "#D9624F"
      },
      {
        title: 'English Course',
        start: YM + '-27',
        backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
        borderColor: "#D9624F"
      },
      {
        title: 'Sharing Session Hadoop',
        start: NEXTMONTH + '-02',
        backgroundColor: "#DACAFD",
        borderColor: "#8652FB"
      },
    ],
    eventTextColor: "#333",
    /*
    eventAfterAllRender: function() {
        
        var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        console.log(events);
        
        //get all dates with events
        var startDateWithEvent = [];
        var endDateWithEvent = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          startDateWithEvent[i] = events[i].start._i;
          endDateWithEvent[i] = events[i].end._i;
        }
        startDateWithEvent = startDateWithEvent.push(endDateWithEvent);
        var dateWithEvent = startDateWithEvent.filter(function(item, pos) {
          return startDateWithEvent.indexOf(item) == pos;
        });
        console.log(dateWithEvent);
      
        //get event colors of each date
        for (var i = 0; i < dateWithEvent.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < events.length; j++) {
            if (dateWithEvent[i] == events[j].start._i) {
              var eventObject = {};
              eventObject.date = dateWithEvent[i];
              eventObject.title = events[j].title;
              eventObject.backgroundColor = events[j].backgroundColor;
              eventObject.borderColor = events[j].borderColor;
              dayArray.push(eventObject);
            }
          }
        }
      
        //get hidden only events
        for (var i = 0; i < dayArray.length; i++) {
          
        }
    }*/
  });
});
```

```css
#calendar table {
  display: table;
  border: none !important;
}

.calendar-example {
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.calendar-example h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.calendar-example a[data-goto] {
  color: #444;
}

.fc-title {
  font-size: 12px !important; 
}

.fc-center h2 {
 font-size: 22px; 
 color: #00c983;
 font-weight: 400;
}

#calendar thead {
  border: none !important; 
}

.fc-day-header {
  border: none !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.fc-head {
  line-height: 40px;
  border: none !important;
}

.fc-body {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.fc-day {
  /*border-left: none !important;
  border-right: none !important;*/
}

.fc-head-container {
  /*border-right: none !important;
  border-left: none !important;*/
}

.fc-day-number {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #777;
}

.fc-day-number:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #777;
}

.fc-today {
  background-color: #E6FAF3 !important; 
}

.fc-today .fc-day-number {
  background-color: #00c983; 
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

.fc-widget-content {
  border-right: solid 8px #f8f8f8 !important;
  border-left: solid 8px #f8f8f8 !important;
}

.fc-more-cell > div {
 text-align: right;
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #777;
}

.fc-more-cell > div > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.fc-content {
  padding: 1px 4px;
}

.fc-widget-header {
  border: none !important; 
}

.fc-time {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fc-time.fc-widget-content {
  border: none;
}

.fc-time-grid .fc-slats .fc-minor td {
  border-top-style: none !important; 
}

.fc-axis.fc-time.fc-widget-content {
  transform: translate(-8px, -12px);
}

.fc-popover.fc-more-popover,
.fc-popover.fc-more-popover .fc-widget-header,
.fc-popover.fc-more-popover .fc-widget-content {
  background-color: #fff !important; 
}

.fc-axis.fc-widget-content {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#calendar .dot-event {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.red {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: "#000";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css">

<div id="calendar"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to get the properties (especially outline and background colors) of each hidden events? Because I want to represent the hidden events as dots, just like this:

[image]

I tried to retrieve all events using `var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');` but I couldn't see anything that differentiate hidden and visible events. There's nothing on the documentation that is remotely close to help me on this problem.

If that's not possible, at least please give me an idea how to transform all events to dots only on mobile/smaller screen. Changing the .js of the FullCalendar isn't possible solution for now, because I want to display it on snippet. Also, is there any way to collect events each days? Maybe I can go from there.

I'm sorry for the bad code since I'm not a developer, and this is the first time I use this plugin. Any help appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: by hidden event what you ment.? Disabled events.! or Events which are before today or hidden events due to multiple events in a day.??

Comment: @weBBer the latter :)

Comment: @Rosiana what do you mean by **hidden event**?

Comment: @VicJordan the ones that collapsed into in example "+2 more" etc :)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe, instead of getting hidden events, you could try to change events' style based on the view type. Then, in month view events would be dots.
You could use the eventRender callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender)

You can also filter all client events loaded by the current view and get its properties using `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', filter)` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents)

Comment: But are there differentiation in data between hidden and visible events? Since as far as I know `var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');` only show me the things on my json file.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no differentiation. But you could apply a filter and get, for example, the view's events, like this example: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27949739/6406678)

Comment: If you won't be able to get all hidden events, render all of them and modify them using CSS and fullcalendar callbacks. Maybe this could help you: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753510/fullcalendar-render-events-in-month-view-horizontally-same-table-cell)

Comment: Unfortunately changing the fullcalendar.js directly can't be a solution for now...

Answer (score 5):

Run the snippet and see if that's what you wanted?

**The CSS part:**

1. I added some new CSS which you can find after `/* New CSS */` in the snippet. I commented out the `#calendar .dot-event`, but you can style the dots via `.fc-month-view .fc-day .fc-event-dot`. (I.e. I used the existing dots styles/`class` in FullCalendar)

**The JS part:**

1. I removed the `dayArray` because it's not necessary. Then I set `eventLimit` to (and it must be) `false`. I also used `eventAfterRender` and *not* `eventAfterAllRender`, and the only JS I added are in the `eventAfterRender` callback function.

**The HTML part:**

*Basically, no changes.* (except those changed dynamically via JavaScript)

(You can also just *compare* my snippet with yours to see what changed.)

```js
$(function() {

      var todayDate = moment().startOf('day');
      var YM = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM');
      var YESTERDAY = todayDate.clone().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      var TODAY = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      var TOMORROW = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      var NEXTMONTH = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM');

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: false, // Always FALSE
        navLinks: true,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
        views: {
        basic: {
          // options apply to basicWeek and basicDay views
        },
        agenda: {
          // options apply to agendaWeek and agendaDay views
        },
        week: {
          columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd D',
          titleFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'
        },
        day: {
          // options apply to basicDay and agendaDay views
        }
      },
        events: [
          {
            title: 'The AI Summit 2016',
            start: YM + '-03',
            end: YM + '-06',
            backgroundColor: "#BCE4FD",
            borderColor: "#26A8FB"
          },
          {
            title: 'Spring 2016',
            start: YM + '-09',
            end: YM + '-14',
            backgroundColor: "#BCE4FD",
            borderColor: "#26A8FB"
          },
          {
            title: 'Virtual Assistant Summit',
            start: YM + '-17',
            end: YM + '-20',
            backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
            borderColor: "#D9624F"
          },
          {
            title: "O'Reilly Summit 2016",
            start: YM + '-23',
            end: YM + '-26',
            backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
            borderColor: "#D9624F"
          },
          {
            title: 'SIGCHI 2016 Conference',
            start: YM + '-18',
            backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
            borderColor: "#D9624F"
          },
          {
            title: 'Les Inggris 2016 Q4',
            start: YM + '-11',
            backgroundColor: "#BCE4FD",
            borderColor: "#26A8FB"
          },
          {
            title: 'Minds Mastering Mac',
            start: YM + '-05',
            end: YM + '-07',
            backgroundColor: "#eee",
            borderColor: "#aaa"
          },
          {
            title: 'AAAI-16',
            start: YM + '-18',
            end: YM + '-20',
            backgroundColor: "#eee",
            borderColor: "#aaa"
          },
          {
            title: 'Service Experience',
            start: YM + '-26',
            end: YM + '-29',
            backgroundColor: "#eee",
            borderColor: "#aaa"
          },
          {
            title: 'Les Bahasa Perancis',
            start: YM + '-26',
            backgroundColor: "#B3EFDA",
            borderColor: "#00c983"
          },
          {
            title: 'SMS Las Vegas 2016',
            start: YM + '-27',
            backgroundColor: "#DACAFD",
            borderColor: "#8652FB"
          },
          {
            title: 'Leadership Training',
            start: YM + '-27',
            backgroundColor: "#DACAFD",
            borderColor: "#8652FB"
          },
          {
            title: 'Leadership Training 2',
            start: YM + '-28',
            end: YM + '-30',
            backgroundColor: "#DACAFD",
            borderColor: "#8652FB"
          },
          {
            title: 'Leadership Camp Winter 2016',
            start: YM + '-27',
            backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
            borderColor: "#D9624F"
          },
          {
            title: 'English Course',
            start: YM + '-27',
            backgroundColor: "#FFBCBA",
            borderColor: "#D9624F"
          },
          {
            title: 'Sharing Session Hadoop',
            start: NEXTMONTH + '-02',
            backgroundColor: "#DACAFD",
            borderColor: "#8652FB"
          },
        ],
        eventTextColor: "#333",
        eventAfterRender: function( event, element, view ){
          // Enable for the 'month' view only.
          if ( 'month' !== view.name ) {
            return;
          }

          var a = moment( event.start, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ),
            b = moment( event.end, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ),
            duration = moment.duration( b.diff( a ) ),
            row = element.closest( '.fc-row' ),
            d = a.clone(), i, c;

          var title = event.title;
          if ( b.isValid() ) {
            title += ' (' + $.fullCalendar.formatRange( a, b, 'MMM D YYYY' ) + ')';
          }

          // Add the event's "dot", styled with the appropriate background color.
          for ( i = 0; i <= duration._data.days; i++ ) {
            if ( 0 === 1 ) {
              c = a;
            } else {
              d.add( 1, 'days' );
              c = d;
            }

            row.find( '.fc-day[data-date="' + c.format( 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) + '"]' )
              .append(
                '<a href="#" class="fc-event-dot" onclick="return false;" ' +
                  'style="background-color: ' + event.backgroundColor + ';" ' +
                  'title="' + title + '"></a>'
              );
          }

          // Here you can either completely remove the default element, or just
          // hide it visually on screen.
          element.remove();
          //element.addClass( 'hidden' );
        }
          });
    });
```

```css
#calendar table {
  display: table;
  border: none !important;
}

.calendar-example {
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.calendar-example h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.calendar-example a[data-goto] {
  color: #444;
}

.fc-title {
  font-size: 12px !important; 
}

.fc-center h2 {
 font-size: 22px; 
 color: #00c983;
 font-weight: 400;
}

#calendar thead {
  border: none !important; 
}

.fc-day-header {
  border: none !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.fc-head {
  line-height: 40px;
  border: none !important;
}

.fc-body {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.fc-day {
  /*border-left: none !important;
  border-right: none !important;*/
}

.fc-head-container {
  /*border-right: none !important;
  border-left: none !important;*/
}

.fc-day-number {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #777;
}

.fc-day-number:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #777;
}

.fc-today {
  background-color: #E6FAF3 !important; 
}

.fc-today .fc-day-number {
  background-color: #00c983; 
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

.fc-widget-content {
  border-right: solid 8px #f8f8f8 !important;
  border-left: solid 8px #f8f8f8 !important;
}

.fc-more-cell > div {
 text-align: right;
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #777;
}

.fc-more-cell > div > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.fc-content {
  padding: 1px 4px;
}

.fc-widget-header {
  border: none !important; 
}

.fc-time {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fc-time.fc-widget-content {
  border: none;
}

.fc-time-grid .fc-slats .fc-minor td {
  border-top-style: none !important; 
}

.fc-axis.fc-time.fc-widget-content {
  transform: translate(-8px, -12px);
}

.fc-popover.fc-more-popover,
.fc-popover.fc-more-popover .fc-widget-header,
.fc-popover.fc-more-popover .fc-widget-content {
  background-color: #fff !important; 
}

.fc-axis.fc-widget-content {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/*#calendar .dot-event {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}*/

.red {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: "#000";
}

/* New CSS */

.fc-month-view .fc-row .fc-day {
  /* Aligns the event dots at the bottom of the cell. */
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.fc-month-view .fc-day .fc-event-dot {
  cursor: default;
  /* Gives some spacing between the dots in a cell. */
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.fc-month-view .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css">

<h3>Hover over the dot.</h3>

<div id="calendar"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort! :) Unfortunately, I just want the dots only to replace the hidden events, not all the events. :)

Comment: I actually knew about that. :) But you know, the answer might help someone else looking to show *all* events as dots. ;)

Answer (score 3):

in this situation the full calendar provide the event Render function.all events going through event render you have to check the each events according to that put the design for dot etc.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {

    console.log(event);//here each event printed one bu one as render.start 
                        //and end date of event
     if(event.end){
        ///check the start and end date difference

       }else {
         //No end date for event       
       }
       if(event.backgroundColor == '#BCE4FD'){

           }     }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all title of your question ***Full Calendar get hidden events properties*** is not your exact requirement. Because in this regard @Mariana has already answered.

Your actual **requirement is to show events as dots** using full calendar.

Answer to this requirement is that **currently [Full Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) is not providing feature to display events as colored dots**.

But you have below **alternatives** to achieve this:

1. Use [Bootstrap Calendar](http://bootstrap-calendar.eivissapp.com/) which is easy to use and integrate as well. [GitHub](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar)
2. Use [Angular Bootstrap Calendar](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#!?example=kitchen-sink) but for that you need to use AngularJS in your project. *Screenshot of expected output in your question is from Angular Bootstrap Calendar*.
3. Customize [Full Calendar library](https://fullcalendar.io/) as per your requirement (of course this is time taking and not a good solution)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete solution, but this may help as a quick fix that gets you part of the way there.

You can convert the "more" links into a corresponding number of dots that can be clicked as a group to display the popover by doing something like the following:

Set `eventLimitText: ''` to remove the "more" text (makes getting the number of events from the text a bit easier). Then, get all the "more" links and convert them to the relevant number of dots.

Example JS:

```
$('.fc-more').each((i, elem) => {
  const $elem = $(elem);
  let num = $elem.text();
  num = parseInt(num.substring(1));
  $elem.text('');
  for (let j = 0; j < num; j++) {
    $elem.append('<div class="dot"></div>');
  }
});
```

Example CSS:

```
.dot {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Important to note that this does not create an individually clickable dot that corresponds to a single event matching its event color. Getting to that solution may not be trivial (you might have to set `eventLimit: false` and loop through all the `clientEvents` to determine which days have more events than you want, convert the extra events into individually clickable dots based on the event object color and other properties, create your own popover for display on click, etc).